# Easy way to tell what branch your working directory is in with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

If I create a new branch using hg:

```
  $ hg branch newbranch
```

And then look at branches:

```
 $ hg branches
 default                       194:d9df55198e53
 newbranch                     193:a36a491b8507 (inactive)
```

newbranch is marked as (inactive), despite my working directly being currently mapped to it.

If I do a commit, default will then be flagged (inactive).

However, if I switch to default, merge, and commit, then switch back to newbranch, newbranch will say (inactive) again.

This is a bit of a pain, because I may do that on a friday night, and not come back to it until Monday, and not know what branch my working directory is actually pointed at.

So, is there a better way to tell, or should I always make it my workflow to specify the branch I want to work in before I start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though `hg summary` will tell you what branch you're on, so will `hg branch` without a branch name argument. Let's say I've never created a branch called `mybranch` before, but I want to start it:

```
> hg branch
default

> hg branch mybranch
marked working directory as branch mybranch
```

And now I've worked for a bit and want to commit, but forgot if I set the branch name for this next commit or not:

```
> hg branch
mybranch
```

Oh, I did.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just discovered hg sum:

```
$ hg sum
parent: 195:d0a2617b4b51 tip
 [Commit Message]
branch: newbranch
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
```

So I guess this is how you do it?